# Filtering filenames returned by dir

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to filter for files that have bytes >0 and names that is not `.DS_Store` with the following:

```
photos=dir('Test');
photos=photos([photos.bytes]>0 & strcmp([photos.name], '.DS_Store') ~= 1)
```

But the string `.DS_Store` still passes through the filter. Does anyone know why?

EDIT:

`dir('Test')` gives a 4×1 struct array with fields:

```
name
folder
date
bytes
isdir
datenum
```

After the filter, `disp(dir(photos))` returns the following:

```
  Columns 1 through 4

    '.DS_Store'    'a.jpg'    'Pizza.jpg'    'Planetbox.jpg'
```

Comment: @SardarUsama Sorry, fixed the typo. `photos=dir('Test')` gives a structure array with 6 Fields: name, folder, date, bytes, isdir and datnum.

Comment: @SardarUsama I'm not sure if there's much more I can provide since the code is already quite minimal and `dir` is a built-in function. I've added some output.

Comment: I feel like there is something odd with your logical condition. Are you sure you want to use `&`here? You would only remove '.DS_Store if its size is above 0 bytes. I feel like you want to remove it if its size is 0 OR it is named '.DS_Store'. Also `~= 1` is probably better written as `==0`

Comment: @Finn But my filter is a positive filter, i.e. the files pass through the filter if size is >0 AND it is not named '.DS_Store'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it with:

```
photos=dir('Test');
photos=photos([photos.bytes]>0 & strcmp({photos.name}, '.DS_Store') ~= 1)
```

Comment: @SardarUsama No, it was't a typographical error, but a conceptual error.